# Why mysql and perl base64 string encoding is different?

Tags: mysql, perl, base64

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Digest;
say Digest->new( 'SHA-1' )->add('test')->b64digest; # qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M


SELECT TO_BASE64(SHA1('test')); # YTk0YThmZTVjY2IxOWJhNjFjNGMwODczZDM5MWU5ODc5ODJmYmJkMw==
```

So same ASCII word `test` encoded as `qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M` in Perl and as `YTk0YThmZTVjY2IxOWJhNjFjNGMwODczZDM5MWU5ODc5ODJmYmJkMw==` in MySQL.

Why ?

Comment: Seams/feels like Perl most likely gives back the RAW bytes out off `Digest->new( 'SHA-1' )->add('test')` instead of giving hexadecimal digits which MySQL does with `SHA1()`...

Comment: Yup, that's it: `perl -MDigest -MMIME::Base64 -E 'say encode_base64(Digest->new("SHA-1")->add("test")->hexdigest)'` -> `YTk0YThmZTVjY2IxOWJhNjFjNGMwODczZDM5MWU5ODc5ODJmYmJkMw==`

Comment: @RaymondNijland You should make that an answer.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The right educated guess. You should get credit for it.

Comment: *"The right educated guess. You should get credit for it"* @Shawn fair enough, but i find a valid answer needs to exist with code otherwise it is not really a answer.. Anyhow i can't program in Perl as i never done it most likely i could as Perl seams/feels comparable with PHP or Python for that matter ..

Comment: Note that there's no point in base64-encoding hex. And if you have to choose between hex and base64, base64 will produce a shorter string

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Raymond, you're looking at the results of two different calculations.

Your perl prints out the base64 encoded SHA-1 digest of `"test"`. Your MySQL query takes the base16 encoded SHA-1 digest of `"test"` and then base64 encodes that string.

Consider a perl one-liner that does the same two steps as the `SELECT`:

```
$ perl -MDigest -MMIME::Base64 -E 'say encode_base64(Digest->new("SHA-1")->add("test")->hexdigest)'
YTk0YThmZTVjY2IxOWJhNjFjNGMwODczZDM5MWU5ODc5ODJmYmJkMw==
```

and the [MySQL query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e475f31c35e4bc8172192fc6f5c0893)

```
SELECT to_base64(unhex(sha1('test')))
```

which gives `qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=`, like your perl but with padding added.

I'd stick with base16/hex versions, though, as that's what people are used to seeing for digests: `a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3` for the SHA-1 of `"test"`.